# filters を使用して日付の形式を変更したい

Tags: javascript, vue.js

#### 実現したいことと現状の問題点

日付の形式を変更したいが、`dt.getMonth` の箇所がエラーになる。
引数 `dt` が、`itemLimit` の値 (2021－08－18) を取得しているものと考えているが、ここが違うのかもしれない。

#### 試したことや調べたこと

リファレンスを確認したところ、引数 `dt` は `itemLimit` の値を取得しているように思える。しかし、他に原因が思いつかない。

解決策が分かる方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授いただけると大変助かります。
よろしくお願いいたします。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
Error in render: "TypeError: dt.getMonth is not a function"
```

**ソースコード:**

Fiddleでデモ―コードを作成しました。
https://jsfiddle.net/uco3hqe9/3/

```
<p>{{ itemLimit | formatDate}}</p> 

var vue = new Vue({
 el:"#app",
 data: {
  itemLimit : '2021-08-18'
  },
 filters: {
    formatDate: function(dt){
      let m = ('0' + (dt.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
      let d = ('0' + dt.getDate()).slice(-2);
      return (m + '/' + d);
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: `formatDate` 関数の引数である `dt` は Date 型のインスタンスではなく、単なる文字列なので `return dt.slice(5).replace(/-/, '/');` で十分ではないでしょうか。

Comment: その通りですね。解決です、ありがとうございます。